# Did big corporate organizations exist in Treta yuga and Dvapara yuga?

Tags: yuga

In today's world we are seeing so many corporate organizations for everything and they are controlling and affecting many of our lives in their desired way. And also many giant corporations have so much influence in Government decisions

My question is in Treta yuga and Dvapara yuga, and in Rama's kingdom and Krishna's kingdom, did these corporate organizations exist? If they existed how did they work, how King(Rama or Krishna) controlled over these organizations? Or what kind of influence does these had on King's administration?

Comment: I think Capitalism or corporate lobbying is peculiar feature of Kali Yuga.

Comment: If there are kings and kingdoms, it implies that there is monarchy. It is only the king's decision which is final. No one influences his decisions(They used to rule for the welfare of the people). There were no business organisations at those times which influenced kings. There were rich merchants but didn't interfere in administration. It was completely dependent on king.